# How to Json file expand like web config's environment variables on c# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

on my project I read the data from a json file with a url list and created a class. I take those urls from within the class, send requests and get the response. My question is, is there an automatic method where I can run this json file separately for each environment, such as web.config, where I can expand?

Inside of Json File:

```
  "ListOfApi": [
{
  "EndPoint": "URL1",
  "Description": "Desc1"
},
{
  "EndPoint": "URL2",
  "Description": "Desc2"
} ....
]
```

Inside of Deserialize Class:

```
 public string EndPoint { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; }
```

So can I automatically generate separate json files for different environments like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aQuU.png)?Is such a method available? Or does visual studio have a feature that does this? I'm looking for method that can convert any json file, **not appsettings.json**. I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution. I wanted to open a thread as a last resort.

**Edit:**
**Execute Code(You can see what code does):**

```
    protected override ResponseDTO Execute(RequestDTO request)
    {
        ResponseDTO response = new ResponseDTO { ApiPropertiesObjects = new List<ApiHealthCheckObject>() };
        string healthCheckListPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory,@"Resources\HealthCheckList.json");
        StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(healthCheckListPath, Encoding.UTF8);
        ApiHealthCheckJsonObject healthCheckObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiHealthCheckJsonObject>(readFile.ReadToEnd());
        foreach (var api in healthCheckObjects.ListOfApi)//ListOfApi is List of class version of what I shared.
        {
            if (!SendReqUrlsAndHealthCheck(api))
            {
                response.ApiPropertiesObjects.Add(api);
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

**And SendReqUrlsAndHealthCheck method:**

```
public bool SendReqUrlsAndHealthCheck(ApiHealthCheckObject api)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(api.EndPoint);
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        bool status = false;
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                status = true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException webException)
        {
            switch (webException.Status){...}
        }
        return status;
    }
```

**Note:** I send an empty request and the service sends requests to those urls. It's clearly visible in the code actually.

Comment: could you elaborate more on what you need to achieve? if I understand correctly, you need to generate multiple json files from one json file containing a list of <EndPoint, Description> values..

Comment: Actually, I want to use different json files according to the environments.

Comment: Yes, actually you were right, i need generate multiple json files from one json files like we did in web config. But My json files must run different environments. I don't want to create different json files for different environments, so I will just create 1 file, it will work for different environments. @MahdiBenaoun

Comment: Alright, can you add the code you're using to parse the json file and send the request to the URL? you can use dummy data. Also please share the code that you're using to detect the current environment.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Of course I'm sharing the parse code and the request code I sent. I don't actually use any code to detect the environment. Then, I'm editing main subject, you can see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: To simplify the situation, you're parsing a list of URLs and health-checking them. What's still ambiguous to me is your need. what is that you want to achieve? what the purpose of separating the json file into multiple files?

Comment: Actually, I want to send a request to different addresses for different environments. For example, I want to parse the addresses xtestapi/api... , xdevapi/api... and xprodapi/api... into different json files. Is it possible for me to do this by shredding a json file? I do not prefer to create separate json files because it is useless (I will use this method at least)

Comment: @MahdiBenaoun Is such a thing possible according to my explanation? Thank you for your helps, this is important for me.